# Display Data from mysql in AmCharts

Tags: amcharts

I'm using AmCharts to create a line chart. So I'm trying to assign data from my mysql database to the chart and  I use this.

```js
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "dataLoader": {
        "url": "data.php",
        "format": "json"
    },
    // we'll skip the rest of the config for now //
} );
```

data.php file has PHP script that connects to MySQL server, loads the data and outputs the data in JSON format.

But I could not pass variable (id) to the data.php file in order to query a specific post (using the post id)

Comment: Please format code correctly. There are missing quotes ..

Comment: AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "data.php",
    "format": "json"
  },
  // we'll skip the rest of the config for now
  // ..
} );

Answer (score 0):

I would change my Select clause in the SQL and do:

```
 WHERE id = 1
```

I think that should do it. But there could be a way of doing it in JSON too and you can probably pass an ID to the URL:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"dataLoader": {
"url": "data.php?ID=1",
   "format": "json"
 },
 // we'll skip the rest of the config for now
 // ..
} );
```

But please ask the PHP or JSON gurus.